# Log4j multiple classes with different loggers and one property file

Tags: java, log4j

I have two classes **A** and **B**. I want to log class A to a.log and class B to b.log with a single log4j.properties in the root directory, my efforts so far:

In class A:

```
private static final Logger l = Logger.getLogger("classa");
```

In class B:

```
private static final Logger l = Logger.getLogger("classb");
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.classa=ALL,A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.append=false
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.A1.file=a.log
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.classb=ALL,A2
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.append=false
log4j.appender.A2.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.A2.file=b.log
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell us what happens?

Comment: FYI this looks like log4j v1 properties rather than log4j v2

Answer (score 1):

This works!

Retrieve via class name:

```
private static final Logger l = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Two class name logger:

```
log4j.logger.my.package.MyClassA=Debug,A1
log4j.logger.my.package.MyClassB=Debug,A2
```